# Booting from sdcard on beaglebone black uses the uboot from eMMC instead of the one on sdcard

Tags: embedded-linux, sd-card, bootloader, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I am following the below link to make a bootable sdcard for beaglebone black. The only change is I am trying to build a 3.14 version of the kernel instead of the 4.4 version. 
When I push the boot button before powering on the BBB, I get "CCCCCCCCC..." output on the serial terminal suggesting something wrong with the bootloader on the sdcard. Without pushing the boot button, the uboot on the BBB eMMC gets invoked and then it successfully boots the kernel off of the sdcard. 
What changes, if any, do I need to make to the uEnv.txt to make this work ?

https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-LinuxKernel

Comment: Are there any U-Boot SPL output before the "CCCCC..." characters? If no, there is something wrong with MLO. Since U-Boot SPL (MLO) performs low-level HW initialization, uEnv.txt is not used at this stage. You can try to write any ready OS image on microSD and check if the BBB can boot from it.

Comment: @LevU. I dont see any characters before these. However I am able to boot the kernel on the sdcard but BBB uses the stock uboot instead. Also do specific kernel version require specific uboot versions or the latest uboot can even work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see 'C' characters on the terminal (while the button was pressed on power up) it means that the CPU ROM code didn't found valid loader (MLO) on microSD. ROM code searches for loader over several addresses (0x0, 0x20000, 0x40000 and 0x60000), you can read about it [here](http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=BeagleBoneBlack_Upgrading_uBoot). Try to write MLO copies at addresses 0x0 and 0x40000:

```
sudo dd if=./u-boot/MLO of=${DISK} count=1 bs=128k
sudo dd if=./u-boot/MLO of=${DISK} count=1 seek=2 bs=128k
```

Check if your MLO is less than 128Kbytes.

You can also format microSD card as FAT and put MLO and u-boot.img there, it also works.